# addeventlistener even firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to ad an event to a form in on my page. The problem is that on the first click the event fires once after twice and after that three times and go on. Also the  innerHTML is not being replaced after onload. I'm pretty sure that is because of the multiple event firing tho.

````
        <form name="search" id="getForm" oninput="requestData();">
            Search customer:<br>
            <input type="text" name="user" id="name"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form> 
    </div>

<script>
function requestData(){

    document.getElementById('getForm').addEventListener('submit', ev);

    function ev(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var user = document.getElementById('name').value;
        if (user !== ""){
            var url = 'http://localhost:3000/users/'+user;
            var xhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else{
                xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xhttp.onprogress = function(){
                //this will print out on the 3rd ready state
                //good for if the application is hanging
            }

            xhttp.onload = function() {
                if (this.status == 200 || this.status == 304) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                    var output = '';
                    if(response.data[0] != null){
                        for(var i in response.data){
                            output += '<ul>' +
                            '<li>Name: '+response.data[i].customer_name+'</li>' +
                            '<li>Parent: '+response.data[i].parent+'</li>' +
                            '</ul>';
                            }
                            document.getElementById('customer_name').innerHTML = output;
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Customer does not exist.');
                    }
                }
            }

            xhttp.onerror = function(){
                console.log('Request error...');
            }

            xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xhttp.send();
        } else {
            alert("Name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
        document.getElementById('getForm').removeEventListener('submit', ev);
    }
}
</script>```
````

Comment: The event listener only needs to be added once, on the initial page load, DOMReady, else as you have it now, each time the function is called you add another listener to the element. That is why you see it being fired multiple times the more you call your function. And as charlietfl pointed out your return statement prevents removal of the listener.

Comment: how would I add it only once? if I move the event outside of the function then other pages complain about not having the event it's looking for

Comment: And the `return` prevents removing the listener if validation fails. Adding/removing listener is not a good approach

Comment: "other pages"...what other pages? Your browser only displays one page at a time. And what is the actual error?

Comment: why do you need requestData(), why is ev() inside it?

Comment: I can't figure out why you need the "oninput" bit at all

Comment: sorry I'm really bad at explaining problems. So I have 3 pages right now that are hosted on the site. If I put the event listener before the function is called and go to another page on the site then I have a console log error. The error is document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: as long as you include the script in your page _after_ the element which it's trying to target, then it should work. Presumably you either aren't doing that, or that element doesn't exist in these other pages. If the element doesn't exist in these other pages, then there is no need to include this script in those pages, so just remove the reference to it

Comment: should I have scripts for every page separately? I was just using a single script for every page I have

Comment: yes you should only include relevant scripts in your page. Otherwise it's a waste of download time for your user, and also you leave yourself open to silly problems like this. Just dumping all your code into every page is not a good design. Break your scripts up into different files according to their purpose. There may be some general functions you want to re-use everywhere, and some which are only needed for a specific situation.

Comment: Well you can also just check if an element exists, _before_ you try to do stuff with the element - `if(document.getElementById('getForm')) { /*add event handler to element*/ }`

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I did not even think about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the event fire multiple times because you're adding multiple event listeners - one every time the requestData() function runs as a result of the "oninput" event. And the removeEventListener command never fires because of the `else { ... return...` block just above it.

But I can't see why you need the "oninput" event at all. It doesn't do anything except add more and more event listeners. You can just declare the submit event directly, without this extra layer:

```
    <form name="search" id="getForm">
        Search customer:<br>
        <input type="text" name="user" id="name"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form> 
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('getForm').addEventListener('submit', ev);

function ev(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var user = document.getElementById('name').value;
    if (user !== ""){
        var url = 'http://localhost:3000/users/'+user;
        var xhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{
            xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.onprogress = function(){
            //this will print out on the 3rd ready state
            //good for if the application is hanging
        }

        xhttp.onload = function() {
            if (this.status == 200 || this.status == 304) {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                var output = '';
                if(response.data[0] != null){
                    for(var i in response.data){
                        output += '<ul>' +
                        '<li>Name: '+response.data[i].customer_name+'</li>' +
                        '<li>Parent: '+response.data[i].parent+'</li>' +
                        '</ul>';
                        }
                        document.getElementById('customer_name').innerHTML = output;
                }
                else {
                    alert('Customer does not exist.');
                }
            }
        }

        xhttp.onerror = function(){
            console.log('Request error...');
        }

        xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xhttp.send();
    } else {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Here's a little minimised working demo to show the event handling part of this in action:

```js
document.getElementById('getForm').addEventListener('submit', ev);

function ev(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log(document.getElementById('name').value);
}
```

```html
<form name="search" id="getForm">
  Search customer:<br>
  <input type="text" name="user" id="name"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I can't do that without getting an error from the browser. Error:  document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: See my last comment on the main thread, above. Don't include scripts in your page if you don't need them.

Comment: hey @ADyson I used your code and implemented it but now the function ev is not firing at all! I do not know what happened. I just copied your code and changed everything to it's own script file.

Comment: and did you include that new script file in your page in a suitable place? Remember the script needs to be included _after_ the form in the page. I added a runnable demo above just to prove that my code _does_ work if used correctly. (Obviously the StackOverflow snippet tool takes care of ensuring the script is included in the right place, so you need to check that you are doing that correctly in your page, and that the script is definitely being loaded without error - the Console and Network tools in your browser can show you that)